# D3 Cloud for images instead of words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, d3.js, word-cloud

Im trying to make a word-cloud like component but using images instead of words. I can't seem to find any library that already does this. I can create a component from scratch but I need to learn how to properly use D3 and I dont have time inside the project schedule to sit down and learn D3.

I tried using [react-tag-cloud](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-tag-cloud) and replacing the *div* component with an *img* component and failed to make a proper cloud because the component doesn't recalculate the height for the images, so they get placed almost in the same place.

I used using [react-tagcloud](https://github.com/madox2/react-tagcloud#readme) and creating a custom render method for images, but the end result is just a row of various sized images.

I tried using [react-d3-cloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-cloud) too, but as I said before my knowledge of D3 is not enought to know what to change in the source code yet.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.